# sqlcmd output file remove header and footer

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

Using `SQLCMD`, I can output the query result to a text file, now, the text file has header:
[image]

And footer:
[image]

How do I remove them during query?

My query, inside a sql file:

`SELECT internal_no, item_no, dspl_descr, rtl_prc FROM PLU`

My SQLCMD command:

`SQLCMD -S SQLSERVER01 -U AdminUser -P au5584 -i C:\text.sql -o C:\out.txt`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

To the top of your query

```
SET NOCOUNT ON    
SELECT internal_no, item_no, dspl_descr, rtl_prc FROM PLU
```

And add "-h-1" your SQLCMD command to:

```
SQLCMD -h-1 -S SQLSERVER01 -U AdminUser -P au5584 -i C:\text.sql -o C:\out.txt
```